# Two Maven projects split service from web app (Hibernate Spring)?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

#
Hello everybody,

i would like to split my web service from the web app. Therefore i have two maven projects.

1. Maven 1 structure: package.service, package.model, package.dao
2. Maven 2 structure: package.controller and different web stuff (jsp
   pages, etc.)

both have a context file:

1. Maven 1: src/main/resources defines hibernate, data source,
   sessionfactory ...
2. Maven 2: WEB-INF/ defines location of jsp pages

configuration:

1. Maven 2 references Maven 1 as project (built path and deployment descriptor)
2. both have neccessary vars added to build path and deployment descriptor

issue:

When trying to run on Apache 7 (eclipse) the resources from Maven 1 are not recognized; (Service)class which is called in one of the controllers of Maven 2 is not found...

question:

1. How can the context files work together to achieve this goal?
2. Is it possible to split the service from web app like described?
3. Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Would you please post the content in web.xml, I think the problem is there, you maven2 project doesn't load the context config file in maven1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Maven2 Project's POM file add the Maven1 Project's dependency like below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>package</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven1project</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :). It did the job Karibasappa! But there was one more error (no session found..).
I solved this with following procedure...

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    bo = (IPatientService) context.getBean("patientService");
    //do some stuff bo...
    context.close();

Is this best practice, or is there ynother way?

Comment: may i know when r u getting no session found error ? means where exactly in code ?

Comment: oh sry, forgot to write when calling in controller only bo.somestuff(). bo = IPatientService = Autowired, so don't know why this is happening...

Comment: is it bo.somestuff() is calling DB ? because DB and transactions may lead this error

Comment: yes, it's calling db. so my "workaround" is correct?

Comment: yes..the problem is with your transaction or hibernate versions if you are using hibernate

Comment: I use hibernate 4, transaction annotation in my service class, calling the dao

Comment: How are you getting session Hibernate 4, hibernate 4 works in this way    Session session = sf.withOptions()
                    .interceptor(new AuditInterceptor())
                    .openSession();

Comment: ah ok, i did it like so @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory; sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(patient);

Answer (score 0):

For you questions:
1. I think the problem is that maven1 context config file is not imported into maven2, so in web.xml the contextconfiglocation param should be `classpath*: not classpath:` Note: all your services are in a jar file, so it's little tricky.
2. Of course you can do it like this.
3. Another way is Maven module. This is also a big benefit of Maven.

Comment: Thank you QQJF! I 'll try the module way at a different time :)